# PHP Parsing an option dependent on what was selected

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dropdown menu in my view called Placeholder - `"add_fields_placeholder"` with the values **yes** and **no**.

When **no** is selected I would like the placeholder value to be left out of the `$formData` array that generates the form html lines that are inserted into the database.

When **yes** is selected I would like the text from the Placeholder input box `add_fields_placeholderValue` to be submitted into the `$formData` array.

How would I achieve this?

```
  public function add()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_value', 'Value', 'trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_class', 'Class', 'trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_placeholder', 'Placeholder', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_dropdown_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add_fields_type', 'Type', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_dropdown_check');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['validation_errors'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
            $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
            $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add Fields';
            $this->load->view('_assets/dashHeader', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/add_fields', $data);
            $this->load->view('_assets/footer');    


        }else{

            $fieldName = $this->input->post('add_fields_name', TRUE);
            $fieldValue = $this->input->post('add_fields_class', TRUE); 
            $fieldClass = $this->input->post('add_fields_defaultValue', TRUE);

            //Removes Caps & spaces
            $fieldNameStripped = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $fieldName));
            $fieldValueStripped = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $fieldValue));
            $fieldClassStripped = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $fieldClass));
            //Default Form Details

            $fieldLabel = '<label for="'. $fieldNameStripped . '">'. $fieldName. '</label>'."\n";

            $formData = array(
                                'name' => ''.$fieldNameStripped.'',
                                'id' => ''.$fieldNameStripped.'',
                                'value' => ''.$fieldValueStripped.'',
                                'class' =>''.$fieldClassStripped.'',
                                'placeholder' => ''
                            );


            if (isset($_REQUEST['add_fields_type']))
            {
                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'input')
                {
                    $fieldField = form_input($formData, TRUE);
                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea')
                {
                    $fieldField = form_textarea($formData, TRUE);
                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'radiobutton')
                {
                    $fieldField = form_radio($formData, TRUE);
                }

                if($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'checkbox')
                {
                    $fieldField = form_checkbox($formData, TRUE);
                }

                $fieldTypeInsert = array(
                                        'name'  =>  ''.$fieldName.'',
                                        'type'  =>  ''.$_REQUEST['add_fields_type'].'',
                                        'label' =>  ''.$fieldLabel.'',
                                        'field' =>  ''.$fieldField.''   
                                        );

                $this->form_model->insertField($fieldTypeInsert);

                $data['validation_errors'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank You</strong> Your Field Has Been Added</div>';
                $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
                $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add Fields';
                $this->load->view('_assets/dashHeader', $data);
                $this->load->view('dashboard/add_fields', $data);
                $this->load->view('_assets/footer');    

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$dropdown = $this->input->post('add_fields_placeholder', TRUE);
$dropdown_value = '';
if ($dropdown == 'yes') {
    $dropdown_value = 'yes';
}

$formData = array(
                 'name' => ''.$fieldNameStripped.'',
                 'id' => ''.$fieldNameStripped.'',
                 'value' => ''.$fieldValueStripped.'',
                 'class' =>''.$fieldClassStripped.'',
                 'placeholder' => $dropdown_value
            );
```